# How to maintain the DataOrder in a wcf response?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-member-order

I am facing a problem similar to the example provided in the link. I want the data member defined in the base class to come at a specific point and not at the start of the response by default. Ex - Zebra should come after bird. Is it possible to do this in WCF?

I tried providing a common ordering for the base and derived classes

Comment: Can you post your code block ?
Because in given example I don't see any issue. It sorted in the order as per the rules.

Comment: Yes correct. My issue is that I don't want Zebra to come first. Zebra comes first because it's defined in the base class right, so I wanted to know if there is any option that zebra comes after the derived class members (in this case cat, dogs, etc.)

Comment: IF you want custom serialization you might consider IXmlSerializable::WriteXml.
Tips here: https://www.developerfusion.com/code/4639/customize-xml-serialization-using-ixmlserializable/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the official document, there is no way to achieve that make the base class attribute sort behind.

> • If a data contract type is a part of an inheritance hierarchy, data
>   members of its base types are always first in the order.

Whether we use the Data contract serializer or XML serializer(the two serializer in WCF), the Order property only take effect in the same class.

```
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement(Order =20)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

}
public class Fruit : Product
{
    [XmlElement(Order =30)]
    public int FruitID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order =10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The above ID property does not work in the deprived class.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.